# setting property read from local.properties inside build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using grade v3.4. I have moved the following properties to a file called local.properties (same directory as build.gradle):

**local.properties**

```
nexusUsername=someuser
nexusPassword=somepassword
```

**build.gradle**

```
File secretPropsFile = file('./local.properties')
if (secretPropsFile.exists()) {
    Properties p = new Properties()
    p.load(new FileInputStream(secretPropsFile))
    p.each { name, value ->
       project.set name, value
    }
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("secret.properties could not be located for build process")
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Could not find method set() for arguments [nexusUsername, someuser] on root project 'some-java-project of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is correct. To set a property you need to use `ext`. Please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties).

So the following piece of code will do the job:

```
File secretPropsFile = file('./local.properties')
if (secretPropsFile.exists()) {
    Properties p = new Properties()
    p.load(new FileInputStream(secretPropsFile))
    p.each { name, value ->
        ext[name] = value
    }
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("secret.properties could not be located for build process")
}

println project.nexusPassword
println project.nexusUsername //property is set in project's scope via ext
```